# Too many connections Nodejs + mysql2/promise

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, mysql2, node-mysql2

I am working in a proyect with nodejs + mysql2 and some times I got the error **Too many connections**.

My connection:

```
import {createPool, Pool} from 'mysql2/promise';

export async function connect(): Promise < any > {
  const connection: Pool = await createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'mendozarq',
    connectionLimit: 10
  });
  return connection;
}
```

Controller:

```
import { Response, Request } from 'express';
import { FieldPacket, Pool } from 'mysql2/promise';

import { connect } from './../../classes/database';
import { Personal } from './../../models/personal.interface';

export const getAllPersonal = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const conn: Pool = await connect();

        const [personal]: [any[], FieldPacket[]] = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM personal ORDER BY creadoEn DESC');
        conn.end();

        return res.status(200).json(personal);

    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error
        });
    }
}
```

So, my question is I have to use **createConnection** instead of **createPool** or I just have to create one instance of my conn.

Comment: How many times does you app call `connect()`? it should only call it once (it looks like you are calling it for every request), and be selecting a connection from the pool.

Comment: I am calling connect() for every request, so I just have to call connect() one time for each controller or just one for every Controllers?. Please I would like to get some example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should only be calling `createPool` once, then select from the pool every time thereafter.

So, it should look something like this. Create a constant that stores the pool. Then in the function if the pool already exists return the pool without calling `createPool`. If it doesn't exist, then you would call `createPool` and return the already created pool.

```js
import {createPool, Pool} from 'mysql2/promise';

const globalPool: Pool | undefined = undefined;

export async function connect(): Promise <Pool> {

  // If the pool was already created, return it instead of creating a new one.
  if(typeof globalPool !== 'undefined') {
    return globalPool;
  }

  // If we have gotten this far, the pool doesn't exist, so lets create one.
  globalPool = await createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'mendozarq',
    connectionLimit: 10
  });
  return globalPool;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!